# Nested bitfields in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, bit-fields

I need to create a structure with bitfields to encapsulate some data coming from hardware. Assuming I use compiler-specific mechanisms to enforce packing and ordering, is it possible to create a structure similar to the following (not syntactically correct):

```
typedef struct _BYTE_OF_DATA
{
    uint8_t Reserved1 : 2;
    struct
    {
        uint8_t BitWithSomeMeaning : 1;
        uint8_t BitWithSomeOtherMeaning : 1;
    } BitsWithMeaning;
    uint8_t Reserved2 : 4;
} BYTE_OF_DATA, *PBYTE_OF_DATA;

static_assert(sizeof(BYTE_OF_DATA) == 1, "Incorrect size");
```

Which can then be accessed as follows:

```
BYTE_OF_DATA byteOfData;

byteOfData.Reserved1 = 1;
byteOfData.BitsWithMeaning.BitWithSomeOtherMeaning = 0;
```

The exact scheme I have described above will not work, because I guess the struct `BitsWithMeaning` needs to start at a byte boundary. I was wondering if there is some other trick by which I can achieve this "nesting" of bitfields.

Comment: Are macros allowed?  Is this C++ or C?  I think C++ because I don't think C has `static_assert`.

Comment: Since there is a `static_assert` I guess it must be C++, so the C tag should probably be removed.

Comment: C has `static_assert` since C11. And the question may also be relevant for C.

Comment: @Morwenn: ah - thanks - I didn't know that (still on C99 here).

Comment: I don't think there is a way around this.  I ran into this issue many years ago, and because of that, I now always do bit manipulations manually instead of using bitfields (:<>).

Comment: It's ugly, error-prone and non-portable (obviously) but a union of (anonymous) structures with explicit padding should do the trick. If you decide to define any non-trivial amount of registers this way then I'd suggest a code generator to handle the gnarly bits.

Comment: I am using C++, but the question is relevant to either.

Comment: What would you expect `sizeof(byteOfData.BitsWithMeaning)` to be? It can't be `0.25` of course.

Comment: @MSalters I understand that's exactly the reason why the code I've written won't work; I'm basically trying to define a type whose size is not a multiple of 1 byte. I have no expectation on what the value of `sizeof(bytesOfData.BitsWithMeaning)` should be. I don't intend to ever have standalone variables of that type. Apparently there is no way to express that intention (which is a perfectly fine limitation).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To elaborate on my previous comment something along these lines should allow the access style you desire. Albeit in a far from elegant way:

```
typedef union _BYTE_OF_DATA {
    struct {
        uint8_t Reserved1 : 2;
        uint8_t : 2;
        uint8_t Reserved2 : 4;
    };
    struct {
        uint8_t : 2;
        uint8_t BitWithSomeMeaning : 1;
        uint8_t BitWithSomeOtherMeaning : 1;
        uint8_t : 4;
    } BitsWithMeaning;
} BYTE_OF_DATA, *PBYTE_OF_DATA;
```

Personally I would much prefer traditional field mask and position constants and mangle the registers manually. My experience is that accessing volatile I/O bitfields in this style invariably leads to inefficient and race-prone code.

Comment: Upvoted, because this does indeed achieve the type of access that I want to perform. However, as you mentioned, this does make the structure itself unreadable; it is not immediately obvious what the structure of the register is.

Comment: The `_BYTE_OF_DATA` identifier is reserved for the implementation (in both C and C++). In C++ you wouldn't even bother with the `typedef`.

Comment: @MSalters: The naming was carried over from the original question and in any event there's a good chance that this _is_ the implementation. These type of I/O register definitions would most frequently be encountered as part of the device headers of an embedded C/C++ compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an union in this case

```
typedef union _BYTE_OF_DATA {
    uint8_t data;
    struct {
        uint8_t padding1 : 2;
        uint8_t BitWithSomeMeaning : 1;
        uint8_t BitWithSomeOtherMeaning : 1;
        uint8_t padding 2 : 4;
    } BitsWithMeaning;
} BYTE_OF_DATA, *PBYTE_OF_DATA;

static_assert(sizeof(BYTE_OF_DATA) == 1, "Incorrect size");
```

So you can fill data in one shot :

```
BYTE_OF_DATA myByte;

myByte.data = someotherbyte;
```

And get bit with meaning :

```
int meaning1 = myByte.BitWithSomeMeaning;
int meaning2 = myByte.BitWithSomeOtherMeaning;
```

Or do the opposite :

```
myByte.data = 0; // Put all fields to 0

myByte.BitWithSomeMeaning = 1;
myByte.BitWithSomeOtherMeaning = 0;

int data = myByte.data;
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the easiest solution might be

```
struct BYTE_OF_DATA
{
    uint8_t bits;
    private:
    struct
    {
        bool getBitWithSomeMeaning() const { return bool(bits&0x20); }
        bool getWithSomeOtherMeaning() const { return bool(bits&0x10); }
        void setBitWithSomeMeaning(bool b);
        void setWithSomeOtherMeaning(bool b);
    } BitsWithMeaning;
};
```

No getters/setters for reserved fields obviously. Ctor probably should set those fields to 0 or 1, as the protocol specifies.